# Bootstrap doesn't allow more than one instance per element. Bound instance: bs.popover

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-5

I'm developing a WooCommerce plugin, then I encounter this error. But in some themes it's working. However I'm a bit worried because it might be also causing this error in future.

Comment: Hi Gilbert, welcome to Stack Overflow. Good question about Bootstrap. Could you please edit your post and include any code that you have already tried. This will really help readers a lot of hopefully get your question ansewered.